# Include a dynamic menu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, menu, include

I want to include a file based on the page name or another unique element using Javascript for each html page on my website.

The script would need to identify the element then load the correct file.

My website pages end with the extension .html -- If I could change them to .php I would and I would be set, but I cannot change the structure.

So for example, a script would check the beads.html for a unique element then it would load the beads-nav.html file that's associated with that element. jewelry.html would load the jewelry-nav.html file, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load external pages via ajax.

With jquery it could be as easy as this: `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');`

Taken from [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Hey brains911, this method seems like it would work for a normal situation. One point I didn't mention because I didn't think it was relevant turns out to be preventing this from working. The website is powered by ShopSite, which is an ecommerce software. I don't expect you to know how to address this issue but if you are curious, the page I have setup for this is at, http://www.artandsoulbeads.com/store/metal_plated_chain_necklaces.html
ShopSite is displaying the whole script instead of reading and executing it.

Comment: Getting a javascript error when i go to the site.  '$' is not defined, which means you need to wait for jquery js file to be loaded before you call .load().  Try wrapping your code in a window.onload function if you have no control over where ShopSite injects your script.